# Is it ok to ignore part of sscanf input string

Tags: c

Is it ok if we ignore part of input string to `sscanf` function.

In the below code , I am interested only in `day` and `year`, so I don't collect the `weekday` and `month` into variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
   int day, year;
   char weekday[20], month[20], dtm[100];

   strcpy( dtm, "Saturday March 25 1989" );

   if(sscanf( dtm, "Saturday March %d  %d", &day, &year ) == 2)
       printf("%d, %d \n", day, year );
   else
       printf("error");
 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hardcoding `March` in `sscanf` may only work 1/12 of the year though.

Comment: Please consider using `const char dtm[] = "Saturday March 25 1989";` and dropping the `strcpy()`, that is really not a typical way to set up a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is fine.

Also you can ignore general strings by adding `*` to the format specifier like

```
if(sscanf( dtm, "%*s%*s%d%d", &day, &year ) == 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you please provide any reference where it is mentioned as such

Comment: @Cheppy This is descrived in [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.21.6.2 The fscanf function. (`sscanf` is equivalent to `fscanf` expect for where to read the input) The `*` is descrived as "assignment-suppressing character".